# Appending node[index] in XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

#### How I got here:

I let my last question on pretty much this same subject gather dust. So, I thought I'd take what I learned and ask a more precise question.

I've got some information in an XML file that I would like to write to various DIVs on my web page, and something isn't going right.

And the last answer I received definitely behaves in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CK6rD/

But implementing the same code completely fails on my server. I'm not sure if it's the AJAX call, or the XML file, or something with permissions, or browser dependent flaws with Chromium. I'm *completely* stumped.

#### What I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#header').click(function(){
        $('p#test').html('At least <em>this</em> works');    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "archives.xml",
            datatype: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
             xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
             $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
             $title = $xml.find( "title" );
             $("div#viewer").append( $title.eq(0).text() );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

#### What I'm asking:

Where should I be looking for my problem if the script doesn't throw an error with Try/Catch and the dev tools in Chromium say everything looks okay too?

As far as I can tell, I have no output from the success function, but how can I test that to be sure?

Comment: the code looks fine. Try to set a breakpoint in the "success" function. if you use google chrome for example, go to the script using developer tools and klick the line-number on the left. Then click your "#header" to run the whole thing. Look at what happens in the success function

Comment: Well, I added a breakpoint at the success function, but the Chromium tools skipped to the end of the AJAX call. So I put in a breakpoint at the AJAX call. Stepping through, I seem to get stuck in a loop in my jQuery library. I'm going to reinstall the library and then look at the specific loop if it shows up again.

Comment: It turns out that the XML file isn't being read *as* an XML file. The jQuery throws an error. "Invalid XML: [object Document]". But as far as I can tell, my XML is well formed...

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the problem was in the AJAX options. The URL *must* go before the type. At least, that's how my AJAX calls are successfully formed in jQuery these days:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "archives.xml",
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "xml",
    success: function(xml){}
});
```